# Use fiexed ratio axes with plotly.express facetrow / facetcol

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, visualization

is there a possibility to use fixed ratio axes in combination with subplots created by `plotly.express` by using `facetrow` / `facetcol`

This example works perfectly fine:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col='species')

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1))
```

As soon as I add the `facetrow` argument it does not adjust the axis.
Can I maybe set a default layout for the subplots using
`layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1))`

[image]

Thank you for your help,

Sören

Comment: Are you trying to make subplots here?

Comment: Isn't that what facetcol does under the hood?

Comment: I took the liberty to add `facet_col='species` to re-create your real issued here. And a screenshot. By the way, you are right that this approach does not seem to work. And I think it's really strange too.

Answer (score 2):

when creating facets `plotly.express` matches axes together so that you can synchronize the subplots when zooming, panning etc. This behaviour is not compatible with constraining axes aspect ratio. The code below where you disable axis matching gives the desired behaviour:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col='species')

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor="x"))
fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(scaleanchor="x2"))
fig.update_layout(yaxis3=dict(scaleanchor="x2"))
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly express facets]